# The unit ball $B^4$ is homogeneous and imbedded in $\mathbb C^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Let $B$ be the unit closed ball in $\mathbb R^4$.

1. Is $B$ a solvmanifold. i.e., does there exist a solvable Lie group $G$ such that $G$ acts transitively on $B$?
2. Can $B$ be embedded as  a CR-submanifold of codimension $2$ in $\mathbb C^3$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$B$ is a manifold with boundary: its interior is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^4$ but neighbourhoods of boundary points are only homeomorphic to a half-space.  So no group of 
continuous transformations can act transitively on it.